# How to connect to a database located inside project folder

Tags: java, forms, server

Maybe it's a silly question, but I am new to databases and I don't know how to do this.

I have the following line of code that I use in order to connect to a database located in my D: drive. How can I change it so it connects to the database if the database is located inside the project folder?
*(I use netbeans IDE)*

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:d:\\Databases\\DataBase1.db");
//I don't want an exact path, I need it so it works idependetly of where the project folder is located
```

Comment: Looks like you can set relative path in Eclipse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611785/sqlite-jdbc-eclipse-database-relative-path

Answer (score 2):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204658/3042546):

> In your code you can use a relative path and it should be relative to the top of your project's directory. In NetBeans' Databases Service you will need to either use an absolute path to connect to the database that exists (in your project) or you will need to provide a relative path...

So according the [SQLite Tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/) connection string should be as follows:

```
    jdbc:sqlite:DataBase1.db
```